# How to Dynamically convert JSON to right DTO class?

Tags: c#, casting, mono, type-conversion, dynamic-data

I have JSON data which I want to convert to correct type and then handle it. I'm using MONO and NewtonSoft's JSON library. I.E. JSON and object must match properties 1:1 to convert to right DTO. DTO's have unique properties always.

Both Activator.CreateInstance() and Convert.ChangeType() doesn't seem to compile.

DTOs:

```
class JSONDTO
{

}

class JSONCommandDTO : JSONDTO
{
    public string cmd;
}

class JSONProfileDTO : JSONDTO
{
    public string nick;
    public string name;
    public string email;
}

class JSONMessageDTO : JSONDTO
{
    public string msg;
}
```

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Server
{
    protected static List<JSONDTO> DTOList; 

    static void Main()
    {
        DTOList = new List<JSONDTO>();

        DTOList.Add(new JSONProfileDTO());
        DTOList.Add(new JSONCommandDTO());
        DTOList.Add(new JSONMessageDTO());

        // ...

    }

    protected static void OnMessage (string message)
    {
        dynamic rawObject;

        try
        {
            // Or try to convert to right DTO here somehow?
            rawObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(message);
        } catch (JsonReaderException ex) {
            // Invalid JSON
            return;
        }

        int dtoCount = DTOList.ToArray().Length;
        int errCount = 0;

        JSONDTO DTOObject;

        foreach (var dto in DTOList.ToList()) {
            try {
                // Doesn't compile:

                // DTOObject = Activator.CreateInstance(dto.GetType(), rawObject);
                // DTOObject = Convert.ChangeType(rawObject, dto.GetType());
                break; // Match found!
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Didn't match
                errCount++;
            }
        }

        if (errCount == dtoCount) {
            // Right DTO was not found
            return;
        }


        if (DTOObject is JSONProfileDTO) {
            AssignProfile((JSONProfileDTO) DTOObject);
        }
        else if (DTOObject is JSONCommandDTO)
        {
            RunCommand((JSONCommandDTO) DTOObject);
        }
        // etc ..

    }

    protected static void RunCommand (JSONCommandDTO command)
    {
        string cmd = command.cmd;

        Console.WriteLine("command == " + cmd);
    }

    protected static void AssignProfile(JSONProfileDTO profile)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("got profile!");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. I had to add JsonSerializerSettings with MissingMemberHandling.Error so that exception gets thrown if JSON doesn't fit into object. I was also missing Microsoft.CSharp reference.

```
class Server
{
    protected static List<Type> DTOList = new List<Type>(); 

    static void Main()
    {
        DTOList.Add(typeof(JSONProfileDTO));
        DTOList.Add(typeof(JSONCommandDTO));
        DTOList.Add(typeof(JSONMessageDTO));
    }

    protected static void OnMessage (string rawString)
    {
        dynamic jsonObject = null;
        int DTOCount = DTOList.Count;
        int errors = 0;

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings ();

        // This was important
        // Now exception is thrown when creating invalid instance in the loop
        settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;

        foreach (Type DTOType in DTOList) {
            try {
                jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (rawString, DTOType, settings);
                break;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                errors++;
            }
        }

        if (null == jsonObject) {
            return;
        }

        if (errors == DTOCount) {
            return;
        }

        if (jsonObject is JSONProfileDTO) {
            AssignProfile((JSONProfileDTO) jsonObject);
        }
        else if (jsonObject is JSONCommandDTO)
        {
            RunCommand((JSONCommandDTO) jsonObject);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you have not created the serialized data yourself from the DTO classes, because in that case you could simply have it include type information in the output. With this information available, the deserializer will be able to recreate the correct instance automatically.

Since this is most likely not your case, you need to solve the following problems:

1. Parse the JSON and create an object with corresponding properties
2. Determine which DTO instance matches the given data
3. Create the DTO instance and populate it using the object created in step 1

I'll assume that you have or can find a JSON deserializer to handle the first step.

You may have an easier way to perform step 2, but the simple approach would simply compare the property names available in the JSON data and find the DTO with an exact match. This could look something like this (using [Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com) to assist with the reflection bits):

```
var types = [ typeof(JSONCommandDTO), typeof(JSONProfileDTO), typeof(JSONMessageDTO) ];
var json = deserializer.GetInstance( ... );
var jsonPropertyNames = json.GetType().Properties( Flags.InstancePublic )
    .OrderBy( p => p.Name );
var match = types.FirstOrDefault( t => t.Properties( Flags.InstancePublic )
    .OrderBy( p => p.Name )
    .SequenceEqual( jsonPropertyNames ) );
if( match != null ) // got match, proceed to step 3
```

The code for step 3 could look like this:

```
// match is the DTO type to create
var dto = match.TryCreateInstance( json );
```

TryCreateInstance is another Fasterflect helper - it will automatically find a  constructor to call and copy any remaining matching properties.

I hope this points you in the right direction.